# VSTO add-in to interact with web api

Tags: vsto, add-in

I need a Word custom task pane that will interact with WebApi. What VSTO template should be used- Web add-ins or VSTO add-in?

The vsto template that create the custom pane using Window Form can interact with webapi in any special manner or using HttpClient?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are talking about COM add-ins (VSTO) you can use any BCL classes for interacting with web services. So, you may consider your add-in as a regular .Net based application. For example, see [How to call web Service in Excel Using VSTO](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-call-web-Service-in-3e082197).